# Basis and intersection of planes

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the basis for the intersection of the plane $x-2y+3z=0$ with the $xy plane$ in $R^3$ ? Also can the basis and dimensions  of these planes separately be found  ??

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to solve linear systems, or what a basis is?

Comment: I did z=0 from xy plane and putting in forst plane we have x=2y which implies if (x,y,z) is the point of intersection then it is equal to (2y,y,0)so basis is (2,1,0)

Comment: Yes, so what is your question? Are you trying to find a basis for the plane $ x - 2y + 3z = 0 $?

Comment: Yes ialso tried for both planes  but wasnt sure bxz i dont have answers for this

Comment: What did you get out of your attempt?

Comment: Basis for xy plane is (1,0,0) ,(0,1,0)and for other plane it is (2,1,0) ,( -3,0,1) . These are right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection is the straight line $2y - x = 0$,  lying on the $xy$ plane, so, it has dimension $1$ and can be spanned by a single vector. It could be $(1, \frac{1}{2},0)$ or, if you want it to be a unit vector, $\left(\sqrt{\frac{4}{5}},\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{4}{5}},0\right)$.

Comment: What is a versor ?

Comment: I used a term taken from physics, sorry, the proper term is "unit vector".

Comment: Its ok how did you find the unit vector

Comment: When found the vector along the straight line, the corresponding unit vector is simply the former divided by its norm. By calling $u$ the unit vector, and $v$ the original vector:
$$u= \frac{v}{\|v\|}$$
In this case $\|v\| = \sqrt{1^2 + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + 0^2} = \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}$

Comment: Ok thank you for helping 

Comment: Welcome :). If you have found this answer helpful please mark it as answer, I'm rather new and i still cannot add comment to other users questions until i reach a certain reputation.

Comment: Me too voting also increses reputation m gonna do itfor you 

Answer (score 1):

*Your solution is excellent.* Taking $z=0$ for the $x,y$-plane is the fastest way to see the solution and to derive a basis of this. This is the 'lazy' (but very good) approach, but does not work at all times. If you have a harder system of equations, things may be more difficult than "taking $z=0$ and substitute". An answer to the second question may solve this.

Let's find a basis for the plane $x-2y+3z=0$. A normal of this plane is $(1,-2,3)$, which follows directly from the equation. Every vector perpendicular to this normal vector is in the plane, so if we pick two independent perpendicular vectors, we've found a basis.
Possibilities are $(2,1,0)$ and $(0,3,2)$. It's easy to verify that these are perpendicular to the normal $(1,-2,3)$ because the inner product is zero.
So for the first plane $\langle (2,1,0),(0,3,2) \rangle$ is a basis (assuming you need no normal or orthogonal basis).

For the plane $z=0$ it's similar. A normal vector is $(0,0,1)$ and so it's easy to see that $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ are basis vectors (by coincidence also normal and orthogonal).

Comment: For showing anew way to solve Thank you so much Jasper and thank u for apperitiating  my way .. 